# Using a form to allow a user to select which excel visual basic (vba) code to run

Tags: vba, forms, excel, radio-button

I have a code that I have completed. I know the code can be improved and I plan to improve the code as I learn more, but the code I have currently works. The code allows a user to select multiple .csv files, or .txt files, then combines them onto a single worksheet in excel. The code is currently a mile long, and all in only one module (although there is one small little function at the top above the modules code). However, currently the code only works for .csv files because each individual .csv file has 4 columns of data whereas the .txt files have similar data but its all squeezed into one column of data. I can use the text to columns feature to separate it into 4 columns and also their will likely be other areas of code that need to be different.

I would like to make a form with 2 radio buttons (text and csv) and if the user selects the csv then my current code runs... however if they select text then my new code will run that I have not created yet.

My question is, how to do this, should I continue to add more code to my already mile long code and just point to that area of the code? If so how would I do this? Using something like "GoTo line"? If my form simply has 2 radio buttons and an accept button what code do I put where?

Or... should the code for the text option be a separate module altogether? Again, how do I go about this? what code would go where?

here is my current code:

```
Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        after:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

```
Sub RT_Multi_File_Import()

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Files to Open")

    Bla... Bla... Bla... hundreds of lines of code does some stuff to csv files...

End Sub
```

I know for the text files I will be using this piece of code instead:

```
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
```

Comment: Look at `application.run`

Comment: Not sure if that's "unclear what you're asking", "too broad", or "primarily opinion-based", but in any case it doesn't appear to be the kind of *specific programming issue* that's on-topic on this site. Looks like this is about organizing/architecting your working code so that it's clean/professional and easy to maintain/extend - if that's the case, implement the part about handling .txt files, make it work as intended, and then put up the working code for peer review on [codereview.se], voicing your concerns about maintainability/architecture: you'll definitely get all the tips you need there

Comment: If all you need to do is a text-to-columns to get the .txt files in the same format as the .csv's, just add a conditional line that will perform that text-to-columns if the user selected text files, and then proceed as normal.  Something like `If obn_Text.Value = True Then <textfilecolumn>.TextToColumns <textfilecolumn>, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, False, Comma:=True` where <textfilecolumn> is the range of cells that the data from the text file occupies, for example `Range("A10:A20")`

Comment: There are many ways to organize things like this, but here are 3: 1) Have 2 buttons, if you click the one for text a text macro is used, otherwise a csv macro is used. Or, 2) you click one button which sets boolean (such as textOption=TRUE) and then use that variable to direct program flow in a single macro, or 3) You do some variation of the above involving radio buttons, etc...

Comment: I am very new at vba & still learning. I am not necessarily looking for how to make it clean at this time. I simply do not know how to implement .txt files part or how to implement a form. I have been reading several tutorials on creating forms but they are either trying to do too much and I get lost or they are using the form to input data to the code or output data to a spreadsheet. I cant seem to find "using a form to have to user select which code to run"... I think I may be able to use this if/then example but do I also need to type code into the form? or the radio button?

Comment: Unless you're not allowed to share the actual complete working code, I would warmly recommend asking for a peer review of your code on [codereview.se] - it's a *much* better & more appropriate place to learn things the right way. Many have gone from complete newbie to professional-level in weeks (months?) just by getting CR experts to look at their code and reading the feedback & tips there. Hope to see you on CR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the simplest structure and logic. Assuming you have created this form (`UserForm1`):

[image]

In the `Sub` which will run from `CommandButton1`, call the `Sub` with your logic (In your `Module`):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call testOptionButton
End Sub
```

In your logic, test which `OptionButton` is selected, and based on it, execute the logic:

```
Sub testOptionButton()

    If UserForm1.OptionButton1 = True Then
        'logic for CSV files
        FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
        MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Files to Open")
        Bla... Bla... Bla... hundreds of lines of code does some stuff to csv files...
    End If

    If UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True Then
        'logic for TXT files
        FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
        MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
        Bla... Bla... Bla... do stuff for txt files....
    End If

End Sub
```

Of course you can make the code shorter cleaner, such as setting the required command and properties based on the selected option, and then run a single set of code based on these command and properties.

But as a start, for a current learning curve, I would use the simple code and refactor it after it is working to a better, shorter code.

Comment: hmmm... this looks like what I was looking for... I will see If I can make this work.

Comment: This isn't "simple" in any way - the proper term is "naive". You end up with a single God procedure that's responsible for *everything* that ever needs to happen. When things start going wrong (need to debug something), or when a 3rd option needs to be added, this solution becomes a horrendous mess of spaghetti code. Future you will definitely regret doing it this way. At the very least implement separate procedures for the CSV & TXT handling.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Well, I think it perfectly fits someone new to the usage of forms (and someone who is generally less experienced with Excel VBA). The purpose in this answer is letting him know how to access form elements (such as `OptionButton`), not teaching him or showing him how to write beautiful code. I hope he can take my "simple" (or "naive") answer, build him a working set of code and leveraging the code level **by himself** - remember, it was not the purpose of the question, the purpose was giving him a working base - and it was given.

Comment: In other words, you are saying "Here's a gun. Here's how you shoot yourself in the foot. See you in the hospital."

Comment: @Hosch250 no - to say that is to give him an answer *not working* per his question. Im giving him a gun, bullets and a target, and showing him how to shoot - hitting the target. Maybe not in the head, and maybe he doesnt aim correctly by the recommendations, but he hit the target. I give him _how to read a form control_, _how to call a sub from a form button click, calling another sub_ and also notes him that he should later improve his code. I think that's enough for him to hit the target (not his leg) and leverage his "shooting" level up next by himself (also hinting him the better way).

Comment: OK, maybe a better analogy is saying to pull the trigger with his toe instead of his finger. You have to have well-structured code or you will spend hours maintaining and rewriting it. Believe me. I maintain/rewrite crappy code for a living.

Comment: By "separate procedures"... do you mean separate modules? So I would have 3 modules right? the first module would be like:  sub myprogram()  UserForm1.Show  If UserForm1.OptionButton1 = True  Then call txt module  end if  If UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True Then  call csv module

Comment: Oh, and it will be fun 10 years from now when you have 10 minutes to fix this and there are no specs and you've not touched it for 5 years.

Comment: @XCELLGUY yes, you can call a separate `Sub` per each selection. The `if UserForm1.OptionButton = True` etc.... code should be in the `button click` sub.

Comment: @Hosch250 If this question would be a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question, my answer would have been different. Again, I gave him the most simple (or whatever you name it) set of working tools. To become a piano maestro you must start with a crappy music, can't play Chopin from day one :)

Comment: Ok... it works!! Thank you so much!!! I have a UserForm1 and a sub multi_file_import that only has one line of code "UserForm1.Show" then when i clicked the csv radio button and click ok it calls testoption button which has an if UserForm1.OptionButton1 = True Then Call CSV_File_Import End If If UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True Then etc...